# ngFor duplicates on every element push to array

Tags: angular

I'm facing wierd behaviour of **`ngFor`**

I have list of array elements and looping that using ngFor, till now everything is working fine.

When I select the other input element I'm trying to add input field using **`FormArray`**. But my problem is, if add any new elements to **`others array`** its duplicating ngFor.

here is my  [stackblitz url](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-id2tzm).

Please check the other checkbox and comes to weird behaviour.

help me to solve this error.

Comment: Because you have specified **formControlName="other"** same for all.

Comment: @SaisivaA I'm using FormArray so it will manage everything for dynamically adding inputs. Even I try to comment input field and try to add dummy text  `<p *ngIf="itemeeee === i+'Other'+j"> sds</p>`. still, it is same issue

Comment: but FormArray dynamically creating with **formControlName="other"**. for all the inputs,  so same is pointing to all the elements, same action applicable to all.

Comment: I'm checking others array elements with condition `*ngIf="itemeeee === i+'Other'+j"` , If I'm wrong can please pointout where I need change